# Why is UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag returning strange UTI?

Tags: ios, swift, uti

If I call this

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import Foundation

var fileExtension:CFString = "7z" as CFString
var unmanagedFileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, nil)?.takeRetainedValue();
print(unmanagedFileUTI)
```

I get

> dyn.age8xs8u

as result. I didn't find any information on `age8xs8u`. Is this the correct UTI for `7z`?

Comment: From the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreservices/1448939-uttypecreatepreferredidentifierf: *"If no result is found, this function creates a dynamic type beginning with the dyn prefix."*

Comment: What does the following sentence mean? "*This allows you to pass the UTI around and convert it back to the original tag*" Should I rely on `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag`? Is the UTI related to the installed apps?

Comment: That means that the MobileCoreServices framework does not know about the "7z" file extension and no application registered it, so yes, it can depend on the installed apps.

Comment: Perhaps you write an answer with that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that the "7z" file extension is not known to the MobileCoreServices framework and not registered by any installed application. In that case 
[`UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreservices/1448939-uttypecreatepreferredidentifierf) creates and returns a temporary UTI:

> If no result is found, this function creates a dynamic type beginning with the dyn prefix. This allows you to pass the UTI around and convert it back to the original tag.

The function returns `nil` only if the `inTagClass` argument is invalid.
With a valid tag class argument you will always get an UTI back, for arbitrary file identifiers.

You can check if the return value has the prefix "dyn." in order to check
if the returned UTI is a dynamically created one or a registered UTI.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z, the UTI for the 7z file 
format is "org.7-zip.7-zip-archive".